# How to group LINQ query to dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a simple model that I'm trying to group:

```
public class PracticeArea
{
    [Key]
    public int PracticeAreaID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

I'd like to group by Type, how can I convert this:

```
var practiceAreas = (from c in db.PracticeAreas
                             select c).
```

to:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> groupedPracticeAreas { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure how grouping works within Linq - I can run .ToGroup(),. but that doesn't give me my dictionary.

I've tried:

```
practiceAreas = practiceAreas.ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Name);
```

But that gave me a cast error

Comment: Which kind of cast error? and what is expected result?

Comment: If you are grouping by Type, what are you expecting the other value of your dictionary to be? Count? Comma list of Names?

Comment: Does it work if you do it all in one step: `var practiceAreas = (from c in db.PracticeAreas select c).ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Name);`? You can't have `practiceAreas` as one type for the first part and a completely different type for the second part (see the difference between `var` and `dynamic`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not throw `cast` exception if both type and name are strings:

```
practiceAreas.ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Name)
```

But this would throw if there is more than one practice area exist for some type. You can use one of following options:

1) Use lookup instead of dictionary. It will create lookup for names by area type

```
practiceAreas.ToLookup(pa => pa.Type, pa => pa.Name)
```

2) Use dictionary with collection to hold all names for each type, e.g. `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` :

```
practiceAreas.GroupBy(pa => pa.Type)
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(pa => pa.Name).ToList())
```

3) Join all names in single string

```
practiceAreas.GroupBy(pa => pa.Type)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => String.Join("," g.Select(pa => pa.Name)))
```